# Flutter Align topRight in a card in row is not working, keep sticking to the left

Tags: flutter, alignment, card

I have a card widget that wraps around few alignments. The centered and bottom left alignment works, but I want to show something on the `topRight` too, it keeps sticking to the left.

Image:
[image]

Code for my card.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => RecipeDetailPage(
                recipeName: recipeName,
                estTimeMin: estTimeMin,
                availableIngredients: availableIngredients,
                missingIngredients: missingIngredients,
                instructions: instructions,
                thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl,
              ),
            ));
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 10),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 180,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              offset: const Offset(
                0.0,
                10.0,
              ),
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              spreadRadius: -6.0,
            ),
          ],
          image: DecorationImage(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.white.withOpacity(0.35),
              BlendMode.multiply,
            ),
            image: NetworkImage(thumbnailUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: const Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.bubble_chart,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 7),
                        Text(
                          "LLM: \$placeholder",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                  vertical: 5.0,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  recipeName,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.schedule,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 7),
                        Text("$estTimeMin mins"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `mainAxisSize` is `max` on Row. You can set to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 10),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 180,
    color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: const Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.bubble_chart,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 7),
                    Text(
                      "LLM: \$placeholder",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10.0,
              vertical: 5.0,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "recipeName",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.schedule,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 7),
                    Text("estTimeMin mins"),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```